# What scope can be used to make a dependency non-transitive by default?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, maven-2, maven-3

If I want project `A` to compile and tests to run but when I place it as a dependency into project `B` then project `A`'s dependencies should not be available to project `B`.

For example:

1. Add `org.example.foo` as a dependency into project `A` (not `B`)
2. Add project `A` as a dependency inside project `B`
3. Add this statement in a class inside project `B`: `import org.example.foo.*`
4. You should get a compilation error on this line: `import org.example.foo.*`

Comment: I'm not sure, but I feel like with the classical Java class-path mechanism is limited so that your requirement can not be achieved easily. You might need to use module-path mechanism to do that, which is available in Java 9. For example, you can declare a module-dependency of A at module B using keyword `requires A`.

Comment: @MincongHuang: Interesting, I might explore project jigsaw a bit more. If no luck comes of it, I wonder if switching to gradle would open more doors?

Comment: Hi, can you be more clear as to why @khmarbaise's answer doesn't work for you?

Comment: @sujit: I don't want to explicitly define any `exclusions` because I want everything to be excluded *by default*

Comment: The accepted anwser is not correct in my opinion

Comment: @Hooli, I think you should unaccept the [current answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49732733/2438951) as per the comments there and consider the others if not done yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specifiy the dependencies in project "A" with `<scope>provided</scope>`. This way the respective dependency is used for compilation & testing, but is not transitively used in project "B".

Here you find the different scopes on maven dependencies: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies

Comment: "provided - this is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide it at runtime" : so what will provide the foo package for A ? Ok it won't be a transitive dependency so it fixes the op's issue but in my opinion it creates another issue.

Comment: `A` will have a rutime issue, it won't run well as foo won't be packaged.

Comment: @ToYonos: Can you please explain in more detail?

Comment: Exemple here : https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope
*when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope `provided` because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.*
Basically, during development and test in your ide, no issue but when your app will run in production, `A` will expect foo to be provided by another module/container/whatever

Comment: Sad, that other possibly correct answers to the OP lost out.

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude particular transitive dependencies via exclusions like this:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
          <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Or you can exclude all transitive dependencies like this (requires [Maven 3.2.1+](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/release-notes.html)):

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>*</groupId>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Apart from that I would really think about your project structure if you might need to change your project A to use different dependencies etc.

Comment: I need to exclude it from the project being shipped though, so in this case project `A` so that project `B` can't access project `A`'s dependencies by default, without adding `exclusions` in project `B`

Comment: If so you have to change your Project A and remove those dependencies which sounds like those are only used in special cases...can you elaborate more in detail what kind of dependencies we are talking about?

Comment: So when project `B` adds project `A` as a dependency it shouldn't have to specify any exclusions. It should just gain `import sample.projectA.*` classes. If project `A` uses `StringUtils` - it shouldn't assume that project `B` wants `StringUtils` as well. project `B` just wants whatever project `A` provides as a wrapper around `StringUtils` and doesn't want to go into a detailed exclusion on how to get there.

Answer (score 1):

For Gradle, you can use the [gradle-dependency-analyze](https://github.com/wfhartford/gradle-dependency-analyze) plugin, it will add the `analyzeClassesDependencies` task :

> This task depends on the `classes` task and analyzes the dependencies
>   of the main source set's output directory. This ensures that all
>   dependencies of the classes are declared in the `compile`,
>   `compileOnly`, or `provided` configuration. It also ensures the
>   inverse, that all of the dependencies of these configurations are used
>   by classes

So it won't trigger a compilation issue but if `B` tries to import `org.example.foo.*`, during `B`'s build you will get this message :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':B:analyzeClassesDependencies'.
> Dependency analysis found issues: usedUndeclaredArtifacts: 
   - org.example.foo:foo-core:1.0.0
```

Either `B` needs its own `foo-core`dependency (it can't use `A`'s) or it's not allowed and `A`'s dependencies remain not usable (no build possible)

Answer (score 1):

The Readme of [gradle-dependency-analyze](https://github.com/wfhartford/gradle-dependency-analyze) plugin mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49693428/2438951) here mentions:

> This plugin attempts to replicate the functionality of the maven
>   dependency plugin's analyze goals which fail the build if dependencies
>   are declared but not used or used but not declared.

Taking this lead, when I checked maven dependency plugin's [dependency:analyze](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html) goal, I found the option [**failOnWarning**](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html#failOnWarning), which might be what you are after.

So, you can plug it to your project `B`'s maven invocation like so:

> mvn -DfailOnWarning=true dependency:analyze < other goals e.g. package >

And, if there are instances of any `Used undeclared dependencies` or `Unused declared dependencies`, the former being your use case, the build will fail.

Only downside is, I didn't find any command-line way to ask the plugin to ignore `Unused declared dependencies`.